# Improve Screen Resolution in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: appearance, screen

This is probably a duplicate question, but i'm not able to find an answer that i understood. I have just installed Ubuntu on `VirtualBox` in `WinXP`. I'd like to improve the screen resolution to `1280x800` (which is what my host OS uses), but the settings only show up to `1024x768` in `Monitors` (also it shows `Unknown Monitor`).
Thanks for any help,
Rajath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Boot into your Windows VM spamming the f8 key and enter safe mode.

2.Once there install the VM guest addtions

3.Go trough the install Wizard and done. reboot

Comment: Thanks Uri, that worked. There is an option under Devices (VB menu) to install the Guest Additions.